# Querying a document in Mongo using DateTime C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongo document with DateTime like this:

```
"_id" : "58064346e74f22124037a607",
    "DateEffective" : "2016-10-18T15:44:01.083Z",
```

In my C# code I want to query my collection for any document that it's DateEffective is before today's date, here is my Builders:

```
var filterDefinition = builder.Lt("DateEffective", new BsonDateTime(DateTime.Now))
var result =  collection.Find(filterDefinition).ToList()
```

my result.Count is 0

any ideas?

Comment: You should use `new BsonDateTime(DateTime.Now.Date)` to disconsider the current TimeOfDay. Not sure if it will solve your problem though.

Comment: I trid that, it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your document "DateEffective" is not a date, it is string. In string key less than will not work. So change your "DateEffective" to date format

the document should in this format

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58064346e74f22124037a607"),
    "DateEffective" : ISODate("2016-10-18T15:44:01.083Z")
}
```

not in this format

```
{
"_id" : "58064346e74f22124037a607",
"DateEffective" : "2016-10-18T15:44:01.083Z"
}
```